# Prove $n^2-2n\geq -1$ rigorously?

Tags: inequality

By intuition, $n^2-2n\geq -1$ is true $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, but how can I prove this rigorously?

Comment: *Really*? You have an intuition about that, but don't have any ideas about how to do it rigorously?

Comment: What does "rigorously" mean?  Should we assume that $\Bbb N$ is a commutative monoid?  Or should we start from the Peano axioms?  Or maybe we should first construct $\Bbb N$ from set theoretic axioms?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the fact that for
$n\in \mathbb R$ then

$$(n-1)^2\ge0$$

$$n^2-2n+1\ge0$$

$$n^2-2n\ge-1$$